# Mitigação de micro DDoS e número de acesso alto repentino em aplicações web com recursos limitados

Tags: apache, lado-do-servidor, iis, ddos

É vasta documentação de como mitigar (reduzir impacto proativamente enquanto ele ocorre) de ataques de negação de serviço em aplicações web. Pessoas normalmente citam servicos como o Cloudflare ou então como por sua aplicação em servidores como Amazon EC2 e fazer balanço de carga.

**Essa pergunta teórica questiona alternativas para problemas em escala muito menor**, sem opção de usar uma solução mais complexa porém com vantagem do problema ser mais simples e para um evento pontual, aonde o sysadmin ou desenvolvedor está vendo a coisa acontecer.

### Situação A: Micro DDoS (ataque de negação de serviço em pequena escala)

Um exemplo típico de ataque desse tipo (apenas parte que importa, o resto já foi filtrado antes)

- São poucos IPs atacando e eles não mudam. Logs de texto mostram eles

### Situação B: Alto acesso repentino

Por algum motivo, seu site fica popular ao ser citado por alguém famoso ou na televisão, passa pelo seguinte:

- Centenas de pessoas acessam poucas páginas. Maioria apenas a página inicial e uma segunda página, sendo que ambas apenas exibem informações e não fazem nada  de especial do lado do servidor

### Comum

Em ambos os casos, o site fica fora do ar e é derrubado pela empresa de hospedagem compartilhada ou pelo pequeno servidor da sua empresa por uso alto de CPU. O custo de gerar e não cachear as páginas é maior do que a demanda. Ambos também não há um problema de rede, pois há banda suficiente para atender a demanda, mas sua aplicação consegue gerar algo no máximo 15-25req/s.

Assumir que não tem acesso root, não poderia instalar novos módulos nem alterar o firewall do sistema operacional. Também não poderia migrar o site para um outro servidor, por questões financeiras ou de tempo, visto que ambas as situações vão ser pontuais e durar no máximo de 1 a 3 horas.

Além da linguagem usada na sua aplicação, poderia também dispor qualquer outra ferramenta que um usuário comum teria, como acesso ao .htaccess em um servidor Apache e web.config de IIS.

**Como, de forma criativa, situação como essas duas poderiam ser resolvidas?**

Answer (score 4):

A *situação 1* é a mais fácil de ser contornada.

Crie um wrapper para monitorar todos os acessos à sua aplicação (Servlet Filter via Java, HTTP Module/Filter caso ASP.NET), contabilize IPs de origem, defina uma margem máxima de acessos e um período de ban caso essa margem seja ultrapassada.

A *situação 2* é um pouco mais complicada, mas ainda assim otimizável. Você mencionou que as páginas são informativas e com pouco processamento no backend - basicamente HR/LW (*high read, low write*).

## Trabalho de casa

Podemos assumir que pontos básicos de performance estão cobertos (conteúdo estático como CSS, JS e imagens está configurado para ser cacheado).

De antemão você pode rodar testes de stress para determinar possíveis gargalos (banco de dados, renders, recursos compartilhados). Você vai eliminar 90% dos possíveis pontos de saturação.

## Antes da crise

Dependendo de como sua aplicação for implementada, você pode definir camadas de armazenamento temporário. Do mais básico ao mais impactante:

- Objetos compartilhados armazenados em memória
- Armazenamento local de recursos, ao invés de remoto
- Armazenamento do HTML renderizado, caso os objetos não tenham sido atualizados

## Durante a crise

Você cacheou tudo o que podia, sincronizando o mínimo possível; ainda assim seu servidor alcançou 100% de processamento. Uma possível solução:

- Tire um snapshot (HTML renderizado) das páginas ofensoras. Deixe preparado um Filter/Module para interceptar todas as chamadas para essas páginas e que emita, como resultado, os snapshots capturados. Se existir algum conteúdo que precise ser dinâmico (informações de login, por exemplo) faça-o rodar em um IFRAME ou ser carregado via AJAX.

Vários serviços utilizam essa mecânica - por exemplo, NewEgg Flash (http://www.neweggflash.com/) ou DealExtreme (http://dx.com/). Você pode notar que a página é inicialmente carregada sem as credenciais do usuário, mesmo com ele estando *signed in*.

Comment: +1, em especial por citar a estratégia de snapshot. Tenho impressão que boa parte dos desenvolvedores **que conhecem também de servidores** vão propor a mesma estratégia. É complicado, mas acho que a maioria dos programadores não tem noção da genialidade que essa abordagem pode ter e transformar até mesmo um site em uma hospedagem compartilhada atender uma demanda próxima a de um servidor dedicado em uma situação de crise.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz, eu tive uma experiência prática de uso de snapshots para substituição em tempo real, e sua análise está correta: Um servidor saturado teve seu load do conjunto webserver + banco reduzido para 4-6% da carga pré-switch.